# STM32F3 Discovery + GNU ARM plugin + OpenOCD - cannot load the binary onto the board

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, debugging, openocd, stm32f3

I'm using the GNU ARM plugin for Eclipse with Open OCD as a debugger. This is on Windows 10 x64. The problem I'm facing is the following error when trying to debug or run the sample program:

> Error in final launch sequence
>    Failed to execute MI command: load C:\Development\stm32-test\Debug\stm32-test.elf
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   Load failed
>   Failed to execute MI command: load C:\Development\stm32-test\Debug\stm32-test.elf
>   Error message from debugger back end:
>   Load failed
>   Load failed

There are several kinds of STM32 project templates that the ARM plugin offers. Most notably, there's the "STM32Fxxx C/C++ project", and it works out of the box no problem. But it's bundled with the old version of STM32 library. I wanted to use the latest STM32F3Cube, so I used the other template - "Hello World ARM Cortex-M C/C++ project", as per the recommendation of [this article](http://www.carminenoviello.com/en/2015/06/04/stm32-applications-eclipse-gcc-stcube/). It's designed for use with the STM32F3Cube, and it's the one I can't load onto the board.

Please tell me what further information is needed for dealing with this issue, or how I can collect more detailed logs etc.

P. S. I have compared the debug configuration settings between the working and non-working projects, and found no difference. Same .cfg file, along with everything else. Is my .elf being rejected because there's something wrong with it?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but are you sure your .elf file is being generated? Is the path correct?

Comment: @bitsmack: yep, triple-checked. Even moved the .elf to a different path, converted Windows slashes to Unix slashes etc. Always the same error.

Comment: @bitsmack: I've just tried the following: opened the problematic project -> Debug configurations, and instead of this project's binary, specified the elf from the other, working project that I mentioned. So, I used this project's configuration to launch a different .elf, and it worked.
Apparently, there's something with how the .elf itself is compiled. Any idea?

Comment: The RAM size and Flash size options in your project match the target board? And also, there is a part in the article, where you have to modify the Flash starting address in the mem.ld script. All of these steps are done in you case?

Comment: @BenceKaulics: that did it, I missed the flash address adjustment part of the article! Thank you, please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the error message it seems that the debugger cannot locate where the Flash begins, so it fails to load the file.

In the F4 HAL Eclipse template this **Flash origin address** is set correctly for an STM32 but because you are using a general Cortex-M project, and so this address is not correct for an STM.

This step is described in the article you have mentioned. From the [article](http://www.carminenoviello.com/en/2015/06/04/stm32-applications-eclipse-gcc-stcube/):

> We need to configure how the application is mapped in the MCU memory.
>   This work is accomplished by the link-editor (ld), which uses the
>   three .ld files inside the /ldscripts Eclipse folder. The file we are
>   interested in is mem.ld, and we need to change the FLASH origin
>   address from 0x00000000 to 0x08000000, as shown below:

```
...
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
...
```

This value can be obtained from the datasheet. Here is the relevant part:

[image]